# How Do I Href Div ID in PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress, href

I am new to coding. Please educate me on how to change href and IDs in the Tab to PHP. I have an href ad1 and ad2. And i would like it to open the in page tab

```
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs flex-column" role="tablist">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#ad1" role="tab"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Maldives</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#ad2" role="tab"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Seychelles </a>
                            </li>
                           
                        </ul>
                       

<!-- Tab panes -->

                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="ad1" role="tabpanel">
                                    <img class="hidden-xs" src="/images/maldives-top.jpg" alt="">

                                    
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="ad2" role="tabpanel">
                                    <!-- ====== Ad2 Image ====== -->
                                    <img class="hidden-xs" src="/images/seychelles-top.jpg" alt="">

                                    <!-- ====== // Ad2 Image Ends ====== -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="ad3" role="tabpanel">
                                   
                                </div>
                            <!-- Tab panes -->
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue. You've only shown us some HTML. What do you want to do with PHP here? Do some values need to be dynamic?

Comment: You can echo PHP variables out with the short echo tag: `<a href="<?=$ad1?>">Hello World!</a>` Add `target='_blank'` to the `<a>` and it will cause it to open in a new tab

Comment: @El_Vanja I changed the HTML page to PHP and the Tabs stopped working when clicked on. I need to change the ID Tags to value php understands. (sorry im new to coding)

Comment: What do you mean by changed to PHP? Changed the extension?

Comment: @El_Vanja Yes i changed the page extension from .html to .php

Comment: The mere change of the extension shouldn't change anything about the tabs. Try to do the following: 1) open the page source and copy all of the HTML; 2) change extension back to `.html`; 3) load the page and copy HTML from source; 4) compare the sources. Is anything different?

Comment: Thanks @El_Vanja and everyone else. Your contributions made it easier to debug (although it took me 2 days). My error was that I did not enqueue my jquery properly.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I finally figured it out. The error was I did not enqueue my jquery properly in my functions.php page. I guess the $handle 'jquery' is reserved in Wordpress.

My code before was:

function addjs()
{

```
//wp_deregister_script('jquery');

wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js', array('') , 1, 1, 1 );
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addjs');

I updated it to :

function addjs()
{

```
wp_register_script('customscripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js', array('jquery') , 1, 1, 1 );
wp_enqueue_script('customscripts');
```

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addjs');

Thank you all.